# c programming, linked list error

Tags: c

When i try to compile the following code, i get the error

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:16: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

and the code is..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    struct planet* next;
} planet;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    planet *p, *start, *first, *second, *third;

    strcpy(start->name, "Suthan");
    start->next = *first;

}
```

Comment: `start->next = first;`, `*first` is the struct, you need the pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Allocate some memory to your pointers.

```
planet *start, *first; these are uninitialized pointers.

start->next // that's dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.
```

2) You're setting start->next (a pointer to a planet) to a deferenced pointer `first`. That's the root of your error.

```
start->next = *first;  // should be  = first;
```

3) Move the typedef name to get rid of the warning you were seeing.

```
typedef struct planet{
   char name[20];
   struct planet* next;
};
```

Comment: It may be dereferencing an initialized pointer, but it won't cause this particular compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Since are trying to assign an instance of `planet` (`*first`) to a pointer to `planet` (`start->next`).

Try this instead:

```
start->next = first;
```

However, I'm also wondering about your declaration of `planet`. Does this help?

```
typedef struct _planet {
    char name[20];
    struct _planet* next;
} planet;
```

Comment: test.c:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
sorry same error

Comment: Change `typedef struct` to `typedef struct planet`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did your struct incorrectly

```
typedef struct _planet {
    char name[20];
    struct _planet* next;
} planet;
```

Should be:

```
typedef struct planet {
char name[20];
struct planet* next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember tripping over this aspect of self-referential structs.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    struct planet* next; /* <-- the trouble is here */
} planet;
```

In the middle of the struct definition, which is in the middle of a typedef definition, the compiler doesn't know what a `struct planet` looks like, but is happy to let you define a pointer to it. The compiler doesn't really need to know what it looks like until you dereference `*next`. By the time you get to the body of `main()` you still haven't told the compiler what a `struct planet` is, only a type called `planet` which happens to be an unnamed struct.

Consider the following approach.

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

typedef struct foo foo_type;

struct foo bar;
foo_type baz;
```

This shows that the name of the struct is `foo` and the name of the defined type is `foo_type`. I could combine them like this:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int bar;
} foo_type;
```

You can resolve the compiler warning by adding a dummy name to your inline struct definition.

```
typedef struct planet_struct {
    char name[20];
    struct planet_struct* next;
} planet;
```

You will also need to address the memory allocation issue that others have pointed out, but this answers the question you didn't actually ask.